# How to draw STRAIGHT lines in manim?

Tags: python, manim

I want to create a video with manim, which includes some straight lines.

Manim's class `Line` is actually line segments. Changing the `buff` attribute to an negative value doesn't work. I tried to calculate the intersect of the line with the screen border, but it's too complicated. Then I expand the line like this:

```
def expand_line(line: Line, ratio=100) -> None:
    ends = line.get_start_and_end()
    delta = ends[1] - ends[0]
    line.put_start_and_end_on(ends[0] - ratio * delta, ends[1] + ratio * delta)
```

It works well; but the animations like `Create` goes too fast.

Are there any classes or other better ways to draw straight lines?

Comment: Negative `buff` values are not supported, as you have already found out. If the animation for `Create` plays too fast, why not pass a larger `run_time` to slow it down? EDIT: I misread your question, now I understand what you are asking.

Comment: I'm confused why the problems you describe force you to draw lines that are not straight.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I mean STRAIGHT LINES, which different from the class `Line` in manim (the latter is LINE SEGMENTS).

Comment: Isn't one line segment the same as a straight line?

Comment: @mkrieger1 A straight line has two ends, while a line segment doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to calculate the intersect of the line with the screen border, but it's too complicated.

You had the right idea here. Here's my solution:

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def extend_line(self, line: Sequence[np.ndarray], **kwargs):
        sr_points = ScreenRectangle(height=config.frame_height).get_vertices()
        inters = []
        for i in adjacent_pairs(sr_points):
            inters += [line_intersection(i, line)]
        inters.sort(key=np.linalg.norm)  # we want the nearest intersections
        return Line(*inters[:2], **kwargs)

    def construct(self):
        a = self.extend_line([LEFT * 2, UP])
        self.wait()
        self.play(Create(a))
```

Comment: Nice answer. I had never noticed that function `line_intersection` before.

Comment: I'd use `height=config.frame_height * 1.02` to be sure that the line goes off the screen (in my case, otherwise, it stops a little bit before the screen edge).

Comment: In addition, I got problems when the line is horizontal, for example, `[LEFT * 2, RIGHT * 2]`.